# How to deep flatten an interface in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

for example:

```
interface a {
  name: string 
  nested: {
    lastName: string 
    nested: {
      age: number
    }
  }
}
```

I want that to become:

```
interface b {
  name: string 
  lastName: string 
  age: number
}
```

interface values will be dynamic, so I probably need some kind of recursive solution to this

I only ended up with finite solutions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution using mapped and conditional types: `FlattenPairs` constructs a union of pairs like `['name', string] | ['lastName', string] | ['age', number]`, then `Flatten` converts this into an object type. I assumed that the nested properties are not necessarily all named `nested` (and do not necessarily have predictable property names), so the type `Primitive` is needed as the base case for the recursion.

```
type Primitive = string | number | boolean
type FlattenPairs<T> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Primitive ? [K, T[K]] : FlattenPairs<T[K]>}[keyof T] & [PropertyKey, Primitive]
type Flatten<T> = {[P in FlattenPairs<T> as P[0]]: P[1]}
```

Example:

```
interface TestInterface {
  name: string 
  nested: {
    lastName: string 
    nested: {
      age: number
    }
  }
}

// {age: number, lastName: string, name: string}
type Test = Flatten<TestInterface>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLYOAgbtAvFAzsRAOwHMoAfKQgVyQCMI5ypaB7FgGwgENCAoUSFABi7LsGARCMLgji4APABUAfFBwBvANoBpKAkJQA1hBAsAZlEUBdAFyWdVqBAAeEwgBNcsRCjSYoAPxQOgA09tpWjnYiYm7SsgqKDsoAvprGphbWUABkwfAskHCg2iZh8MioGBBW-ODQMeKSSqoamjB6Bo1xMnItUFxeMJoADJF2wwCMVim8vPoScGZcAMbQihD4AJKEi8trUOq8UJRcSBB2+ESkx5SbEu52RycnovgAcmcXeAT6Ny93fAQR6HW4ArjEb7UOgMMFQWYnWazXgAehRhwhUJo9DgYTewE+50uvxIYUIX2J11mAnW9zUwlETUISnuOz2qwgyl4QA)

The helper type `FlattenPairs` can be written in a slightly simpler way if the nested property name(s) are known:

```
type FlattenPairs<T> = {[K in keyof T]: K extends 'nested' ? FlattenPairs<T[K]> : [K, T[K]]}[keyof T]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgNgQ2MCA7ACgglgJwM4A8AKgHxQC8UA3gNoDSUWqUA1hCAPYBmURAugC4oDCAA8UqACZ4oAclQQ8KSbKgB+WImRpMuQkXp8yQ+gBpehvgF8abTj34AoUJE1IJxMpVrpGzeO462PieUAgy6DQADHyCUJEAjNaOjkwoOFwIAMbQRIrAAJKo6Zk51I5QUKgIALYQQko4TADmUBVV+RCSQlTtlYhKAHK19VCNLW2VlQpKXT19UwjNo6gArjUARhA4C1bte3uOAPRH1Esr61s45gPAw3UNwE2ozebVD2NPLXsuufkUbm0qGI+SKJWyEBIjiAA)

Comment: works like a charm thanks. can you explain the `& [PropertyKey, Primitive]` part please, is it just a hacky way to fix "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite." typescript error or there are other reasons ?

Comment: Yes, that's just a way to fix that error.

Comment: Does this work for union types like `{ foo: number | { bar: string } }`

Comment: @DaDo It doesn't seem to, but you may be able to get something working with a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). Otherwise I suggest asking a separate question.

Comment: I opened a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69095054/how-to-deep-flatten-a-typescript-interface-with-union-types-and-keep-the-full-ob)

Comment: @kaya3 it doesn't work if we change the outer `nested` name to anything else. Is there a fix to this? Seems like it skip the object entirely before flattening the inner `nested`

Comment: @BoomPT There are two versions in the answer, the second assumes the nest property name `nested` is known, the first does not.

Comment: @kaya3 here's the [typescript playground](https://tsplay.dev/mAdqBN) that explains my problem

Comment: @BoomPT You have a different but related problem. It is not a flaw in this answer. I suggest you keep searching to see if there is an existing Q&A which answers your question, or otherwise ask a new question about it.