# How to deep flatten a Typescript interface with union types and keep the full object path in the key

Tags: typescript

Say I have the following interface:

```js
interface Foo {
  foo: string
  bar?: number
  nested: {
    foo: string,
    deeplyNested: {
      bar?: number
    }
  }
  union: string | {
    foo: string,
    bar?: number
  }
}
```

Now I need a type to convert this interface to a flattened version with the full path names in the keys like this:

```js
interface FooFlattened {
  foo: string
  bar?: number
  "nested.foo": string
  "nested.deeplyNested.bar"?: number

  // if union is a string:
  union: string

  // if union is an object:
  "union.foo": string
  "union.bar"?: number
}
```

The type should work for any level of nesting and any amount of union members.

I already found a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68518274/13575631) but that one's only a very basic interface without unions or optional paramters.

Comment: I don't think you can do this, sorry.

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of [this question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/65919016) except you have some slightly different requirements.  The code there with a tweak gives [this](https://tsplay.dev/W4pg7W) which is pretty close to what you want.  I might be able to get closer, but even so, this question is pretty duplicatey (that's a word, right?) unless you can justify an important distinction between the two (e.g., what's the use case for having `{union: string}` and `{"union.foo": string}` appear at the same time and not as a union?).

Comment: @jcalz your tweaked solution is nearly the thing I need, however for some reason the `deeplyNested` property got lost and is missing on the final result. What happened to it?

Comment: Okay if I get a chance I'll see if I can come up with something better (although possibly not any better than @CRice's solution).

Comment: Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQKdjm) what you want?  I'd really like to see some more use cases though... I don't want to post the answer and then see that it doesn't work for some use case not posted here.

Comment: @jcalz I tried it with a complex interface from my project [here](https://tsplay.dev/N52Ydm) and got an error `'x' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.(2502).` I also realised that I'm using object types in my interface such as `Date` and `Buffer` but you can ignore them/remove them since I'll replace those with primitives soon.

Comment: I can probably remove that error (`any` confused it) but I don't understand at all what you expect to see with an array.  Like, what key should `Flatten<{foo: Array<{bar: string}>}>` have in it?  Dotted paths into arrays are... like... what are you looking for, here?

Comment: Like, how about [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDGjjw)?  Please put me out of my misery soon and let me know what you want to see for your complex interface (and maybe put both input and output definitions into the question text proper)

Comment: @jcalz I'm sorry for your suffering.... you can ignore the array too and imagine it as the type that's in it. I think your last solution is exactly what I need, you can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to approach this, and in my experience they are all tricky and fiddly and fragile and have lots of crazy edge cases.  See [How can an object type with nested subproperties be flattened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65919016) for a similar question with a similarly caveat-filled answer.

In the end, in this case I decided to take the following approach.  We can take an object type and represent it as a union of *`Entry`* elements, where an `Entry` has a `key`, `value`, and `optional` property:

```
type Entry = { key: string, value: any, optional: boolean };
```

So for a type like `{a: string, b?: number}` you would get `{key: "a", value: string, optional: false} | {key: "b", value: number | undefined, optional: true}`.

For the first step we would take the input interface like `Foo` and *`Explode`* it into a big union of `Entry` elements where deeply nested properties are converted to single keys with dotted paths.  So `Explode<{a: {b: string}}>` would become `{key: "a.b", value: string, optional: false}`.  This does the heavy lifting of the algorithm, and we have to decide things like how optional properties propagate, how unions propagate, etc.

A possible definition of `Explode` could look like this:

```
type Explode<T> =
    T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]-?:
        K extends string ? Explode<T[K]> extends infer E ? E extends Entry ?
        {
            key: `${K}${E['key'] extends "" ? "" : "."}${E['key']}`,
            value: E['value'],
            optional: E['key'] extends "" ? {} extends Pick<T, K> ? true : false : E['optional']
        }
        : never : never : never
    }[keyof T] : { key: "", value: T, optional: false }
```

If we `Explode` a non-object type we use a blank key; otherwise we recursively `Explode` all the properties of the object and then concatenate keys using [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types), and decide something with optional properties (I think I made it so that `{a: {b?: string}}` would make `b` optional, but `{a?: {b: string}}` would make `b` required).  It's a mess.

Oh and I wasn't sure what to do with arrays; I decided to just use `"0"` as the key to represent an array index, and so I renamed `Explode<T>` to `_Explode<T>` and then define `Explode<T>` in terms of it:

```
type Explode<T> = _Explode<T extends readonly any[] ? { "0": T[number] } : T>;
```

Finally, once we have the full exploded union of `Entry` elements, we can *`Collapse`* them together into a single object type:

```
type Collapse<T extends Entry> = (
    { [E in Extract<T, { optional: false }> as E['key']]: E['value'] }
    & Partial<{ [E in Extract<T, { optional: true }> as E['key']]: E['value'] }>
) extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never
```

I'm using [key remapping via `as`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to iterate over each element `E` of the union `T` of `Entry` objects; each key is `E['key']` and each value is `E['value']`.  By partitioning the union into those with `true` and `false` values for the `optional` property, we can produce an output type with optional and required properties, respectively.

And, finally, `Flatten<T>` is just what you do when you `Explode` something into `Entry` objects and then `Collapse` those objects:

```
type Flatten<T> = Collapse<Explode<T>>
```

---

Here's how it works on your example here:

```
type FooFlattened = Flatten<Foo>
/* type FooFlattened = {
  foo: string;
  "nested.foo": string;
  union: string;
  "union.foo": string;
  bar?: number | undefined;
  "nested.deeplyNested.bar"?: number | undefined;
  "union.bar"?: number | undefined;
}*/
```

which is exactly the same type as your manually written expected output (except for order of properties, which does not affect type equality).

---

For something more complex, like

```
interface Foo {
    tmdb: number | {
        title: {
            original: string
            german?: string
        }
        budget?: number
        revenue?: number
        tagline?: string
        overview?: string
        productionCompanies?: {
            id?: number
            logoPath?: string
            name?: string
            originCountry?: string
        }[]
        releaseDate?: string
        genres?: string[]
        runtime?: number
        poster?: string | {
            data: { sample: any } 
            contentType: string
        }
    }
    rating: { ch: number; rt: number } | { total: number }
    dateSeen?: Date
    fsk?: number
    mm?: boolean
}
```

we get

```
type FlattenedFoo = Flatten<Foo>
/* type FlattenedFoo = {
    tmdb: number;
    "tmdb.title.original": string;
    "tmdb.genres.0": string;
    "tmdb.poster.data.sample": any;
    "tmdb.poster.contentType": string;
    "rating.ch": number;
    "rating.rt": number;
    "rating.total": number;
    "tmdb.title.german"?: string | undefined;
    "tmdb.budget"?: number | undefined;
    "tmdb.revenue"?: number | undefined;
    "tmdb.tagline"?: string | undefined;
    "tmdb.overview"?: string | undefined;
    "tmdb.productionCompanies"?: undefined;
    "tmdb.productionCompanies.0.id"?: number | undefined;
    "tmdb.productionCompanies.0.logoPath"?: string | undefined;
    "tmdb.productionCompanies.0.name"?: string | undefined;
    "tmdb.productionCompanies.0.originCountry"?: string | undefined;
    "tmdb.releaseDate"?: string | undefined;
    "tmdb.genres"?: undefined;
    "tmdb.runtime"?: number | undefined;
    "tmdb.poster"?: string | undefined;
    dateSeen?: undefined;
    fsk?: number | undefined;
    mm?: boolean | undefined;
} */
```

which is reasonable, I think.

---

Of course there are likely edge cases where this will do something you don't want.  They might be addressed by changing how `Explode` works, or maybe nothing you do will work for all of your intended use cases and you'll have to decide either to give up some of your use cases, or give up on `Flatten`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=4.4.2#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4CgkikNgAXCNAMwWQDEB7BvQ4tqpgLiSjM2Cys2RAEYg0Afm7AArmBGUhw4NAoATbgWHakHBt178sAGiU6kaiBBgAbAJ4A5VRA0tz5sZOlyFaMzoBffyIg8xlgDAZgAz5SHAAfN3ciPRijU2TRcSkkWXlFc1DiIKUyOxh6JjobEDIKFTUkAF4katr6gB5GBgA+JQB6ACokMorWqpq6iAbmpPYuHliBAG5-ACIVXhcAOj01tLjV7XDI6MWjI+E1k6jdpn3zw-9PHLzfJETwyypSF0u2DbONTbSzWexOLbAzxrV4+SgfJBfCA-Br-YjXCK3aGw-JoBFIlF-JQBQb9fBKUgUai0cYMNpTBoAWRAshANjmwlSjwEwSQL28uN5gMhdwYD0McSFm3UIKstkcQO22IFvnJ5n6-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-CHjeShjqeuJtj897Aq+tyXrIMK2X+3Fjpmwbx1mtcWTDVTPmAb5fjUSHTqVfdDwRj6Bx1FHUWmjGz0vWQIBxwL8WR5FUfR3sBsfZ8VARrcqYJolVoxj9KG-P8WYDNmacJzn6eA0DwJHKJoNglkfygBGCVponRZAsCIKlmC4LlxbthQincUFwk0eVs7VYlqDNdl6Adcw7C8LIN7GMNpWRdN8X1eAaWtethbtlI8mnaR9njdd7YxbVyXPct+CoB10aaIYOi0DsfmjGd4X0RmriIB4-jBNTuJ045zOMbm6AFepo26f6tBZMgfX3iDoXi6IE7RY2ygC4EIuQ+IGKIDi6YckVjOUnStCe7RbLcvynO9SbquiqQUlyRKvNyGT2ZcCQNKIDsYTq3PNlr24Q7qwYGBI4XPlZ5ZYzVnwNeC1sUCIA6ayelmAB9QsX8sd+kAQCLNMEsvkc5qCiPYQy7EkASDwEgNYS1uDWRYrjNixkkDIJ6A-EqP9n6YX-h-ZoShrKAOAcjA0zo3QelgfAliABpEgepd52AYNqaybEAC0UheSMKAcWA0rM4G-wIW-FB9C2Kf34SAg0pAqDwjzLQxR0iKFIHXvRWBvJ1LmBYdwAABgAElwPQgIRi8wsQAOQsIseglRoC1hrFoQ4zBCDthrFMbgcxVi942ICHojImQj42BPmoyxQTrw2ICckC+V8IqhO8XYGxZCBEIMcXA3AJk7EGhwhgeAaV37VnoZ-OBfBrwuJoDYXiLivExNOGyGxjleTSAvPCZpn4XEqE-MSFiLC2FIA4S47eujUmH2PgZay59L51LiRUqpJRH5NWgjYGoMBeIAKyWojedhP4tAABRKG3ixRRpA1FFlch6Ap8DalRGvrM5AARP48XidYtibFuBePCRAJJTkkAADIkB4T8hgNkHRDnHL1IWPgCAyCXO3tc8a3BSn3MeQaLxLy3nxM+d8voABKZJMimHyLxCgWhhzGEnN6dqFAGKUAMPQSZNpigFljGqsAd+OykBLJWWskRr92V9FXk1TM2Zcx2EhTI9Z5DQEAFVqzSvxao2M1ZYyzCIS0c8DAUJAA)

Comment: Thank you so much!. This should 1. be a native utility type or 2. be included in an "essential typescript types" package

Comment: This is some amazing sorcery! You did mention that it probably won't work in all cases, and indeed, it seems to strip out dates (and probably other complex objects). I was able to fix this by adding  `T extends Date ? { key: "", value: T, optional: false } :` before the first line of `Explode`.

Answer (score 3):

First we can work to create a type that contains a union of the valid dotted paths for your object. Thankfully we already have an [excellent answer giving a method to do so right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58434389/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object).

Using the `Leaves` type from that answer, we can construct your union of paths:

```
type DottedFooPaths = Leaves<Foo>;
// type DottedFooPaths = "foo" | "bar" | "union" | "nested.foo" | "nested.deeplyNested.bar" | "union.foo" | "union.bar"
```

Now we need to create a new object using those paths as the keys, and associate each path to it's corresponding value type in the original object. To accomplish that, we can perform the dotted-path conversion in reverse, and use that to index into our original type recursively:

```
type FollowPath<T, P> = P extends `${infer U}.${infer R}` ? U extends keyof T ? FollowPath<T[U], R> : never : P extends keyof T ? T[P] : never;

// For example, this might produce:
type FooDotBar = FollowPath<Foo, "bar"> // number | undefined
```

Then, if we construct a type where each key is one of the members of `Leaves<Foo>`, we can use `FollowPath` to extract the corresponding value type:

```
type FlattenedFoo = {
    [K in Leaves<Foo>]: FollowPath<Foo, K>
}

// Produces:
// type FlattenedFoo = {
//     foo: string;
//     bar: number | undefined;
//     union: string | {
//         foo: string;
//         bar?: number | undefined;
//     };
//     "nested.foo": string;
//     "nested.deeplyNested.bar": number | undefined;
//     "union.foo": never;
//     "union.bar": never;
// }
```

Which is *almost* your desired result, but it loses the optional modifiers on the keys; although I'm uncertain if there even is a way to keep the optional modifiers.

Comment: Addendum: Building this into a easier to use generic type, ala `Flattened<T> = {[K in Leaves<T>]: FollowPath<T, K>}`, doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure why that fails but the direct approach (where we manually substitute `Foo` for `T`) works fine. If anyone knows why, please comment.

Comment: Another problem with this solution is that `union` is still a union type `string | { ... }` in the result so the nested object is still there. I need the entire interface to be a union of all possible union objects inside the interface (see jcalz' comment on the question).

Answer (score 0):

I might be late to the party, but some time ago I stumbled on a similar problem while developing [dynamode](https://github.com/blazejkustra/dynamode) - a Typescript modeling tool for DynamoDB (more details [here](https://blog.swmansion.com/modeling-with-dynamodb-made-easy-in-typescript-cdada092d387)).

Inspired by @jcalz answer I created a similar type but with all edge cases in mind.

- First it creates a big union of so called `Entries` - responsibility of `CreateObjectEntries<TValue>`

  - `CreateObjectEntries<TValue>` works recursively to the bottom of an object
  - `OmitItself<TValue, TValueInitial>` is used in order to stop if type references itself (infinite loop)
  - `OmitExcludedTypes<TValue, TValueInitial>` is used in order to avoid collapsing specific types (for example `Date`, `Set`, `Map`)
- A crucial part of the puzzle is `CreateArrayEntry<TValue, TValueInitial>` that checks if `TValue` is an array and encodes it so that it can be flattened too
- At the end `Entries` are connected together with `CollapseEntries<TEntry>`.

For something complex:

```
type Foo = {
  tmdb:
    | number
    | {
        title: {
          original: string;
          german?: string;
        };
        productionCompanies?: {
          id?: number;
          logoPath?: string;
        }[];
        releaseDate?: string;
      };
  rating: { ch: number; rt: number } | { total: number };
  dateSeen: Date;
  mm: boolean;
};
```

We get:

```
type FlattenedFoo = FlattenObject<Foo>;

{
  tmdb: number | { /* ... */ };
  "tmdb.productionCompanies": {
    id?: number | undefined;
    logoPath?: string | undefined;
  }[] | undefined;
  [x: `tmdb.productionCompanies[${bigint}]`]: {
      id?: number | undefined;
      logoPath?: string | undefined;
  };
  [x: `tmdb.productionCompanies[${bigint}].logoPath`]: string | undefined;
  [x: `tmdb.productionCompanies[${bigint}].id`]: number | undefined;
  "tmdb.title.original": string;
  "tmdb.title": {
      original: string;
      german?: string | undefined;
  };
  "tmdb.title.german": string | undefined;
  "tmdb.releaseDate": string | undefined;
  rating: {
    ch: number;
    rt: number;
  } | {
    total: number;
  };
  "rating.ch": number;
  "rating.rt": number;
  "rating.total": number;
  dateSeen: Date;
  mm: boolean;
}
```

More details in a [medium article](https://medium.com/@kustrablazej/deep-flatten-typescript-type-c0d123028d82).

Here is a full type to play around: https://tsplay.dev/mAL6kN

And the Dynamode source code: [link](https://github.com/blazejkustra/dynamode/blob/0df7fd5b3d2e19a0e0590707011b6f405c248b16/lib/utils/types.ts#L10)